# WordPress: Where do I view var_dump results being called in functions.php?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

One thing I've always struggled with in learning PHP is figuring out where to view debug code such as `print_r` and `var_dump`.

For example, in my `functions.php` of my WordPress/WooCommerce site, I have:

```
function my_function_name($order_id) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    echo var_dump($order);
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_completed', 'my_function_name', 10, 1 );
```

I want to view the results of `var_dump` but after placing an order in WooCommerce (my understanding of when the `woocommerce_order_status_completed` hook should be called), how I have no idea where/how to view the `var_dump` results.

(It could also be possible my function is written incorrectly)

I've attempted to research this, but many places just say to put `var_dump` in `functions.php`, without specifying how to view those results (of course I could be vastly misunderstanding).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to debug a value, you can put it anywhere before you call `get_header();` in your template to have a clear view of your `var_dump`.

For example, at the top of your `functions.php`, you can call:

```
// Call the function you've created
my_function_name(1); // Replace 1 with a real order id
```

You might also want to change your function to exit the script so it stops rendering the other stuffs:

```
function my_function_name($order_id){

    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);
    var_dump($order); // You do not need the echo
    exit;

}
```

Then simply load any page of your wordpress:

```
http://example.com
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904648/wordpress-var-dump-in-functions-php?rq=1) for a similar issue, where killing the flow immediately after var_dump solved the issue.